# dynamic shift with groupby on dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to shift a grouped data frame by a dynamic number. I can do it with apply, but the performance is not very good.

Any way to do that without apply?

Here is a sample of what I would like to do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'GROUP': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B','B','B','B'], 
    'VALUE': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2],
    'SHIFT': [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    })  

df['SUM'] = df.groupby('GROUP').VALUE.cumsum()

# THIS DOESN'T WORK:
df['VALUE'] = df.groupby('GROUP').SUM.shift(df.SHIFT)
```

I do it with apply the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'GROUP': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B','B','B','B'], 
    'VALUE': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2],
    'SHIFT': [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    })  

def func(group):
    s = group.SHIFT.iloc[0]

    group['SUM'] = group.SUM.shift(s)

    return group

df['SUM'] = df.groupby('GROUP').VALUE.cumsum()

df = df.groupby('GROUP').apply(func)
```

Comment: I just need a faster way, because apply running on millions of rows is not performing well even with Dask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure numpy version that works if the data frame is sorted by group (like your example):

```
# these rows are not null after shifting
notnull = np.where(df.groupby('GROUP').cumcount() >= df['SHIFT'])[0]
# source rows for rows above
source = notnull - df['SHIFT'].values[notnull]

shifted = np.empty(df.shape[0])
shifted[:] = np.nan
shifted[notnull] = df.groupby('GROUP')['VALUE'].cumsum().values[source]
df['SUM'] = shifted
```

It first gets the indices of rows that are to be updated. The shifts can be subtracted to yield the source rows.

Comment: I had a couple more requirements that weren't defined in my question, and since I was able to do it another way using join, I will put your anwser as correct because it anwsers my question very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A solution that avoids `apply`, could be the following, if the groups are contiguous:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'GROUP': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B','B','B','B','B','B'],
    'VALUE': [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2],
    'SHIFT': [ 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
    })


# compute values required for the slices
_, start = np.unique(df.GROUP.values, return_index=True)
gp = df.groupby('GROUP')
shifts = gp.SHIFT.first()
sizes = gp.size().values
end = (sizes - shifts.values) + start

# compute slices
source = [i for s, f in zip(start, end) for i in range(s, f)]
target = [i for j, s, f in zip(start, shifts, sizes) for i in range(j + s, j + f)]

# compute cumulative sum and arrays of nan
s = gp.VALUE.cumsum().values
r = np.empty_like(s, dtype=np.float32)
r[:] = np.nan

# set the on the array of nan
np.put(r, target, s[source])

# set the sum column
df['SUM'] = r

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   GROUP  SHIFT  VALUE   SUM
0      A      2      1   NaN
1      A      2      2   NaN
2      A      2      3   1.0
3      A      2      4   3.0
4      A      2      5   6.0
5      A      2      6  10.0
6      B      3      7   NaN
7      B      3      8   NaN
8      B      3      9   NaN
9      B      3      0   7.0
10     B      3      1  15.0
11     B      3      2  24.0
```

With the exception of building the slices (`source` and `target`) all computations are done in a pandas/numpy level that should be fast. The idea is to manually simulate what would be done in the apply function.