# Pandas dynamic Groupby and Shift

Tags: pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I am attempting to perform a dynamic shift within a groupby object.  In this case my grouping is Account and each account will have the column Valuation shifted by *minus* the number of rows specified in the column Shift.  There was a similar question a while ago but that involved a cumsum, where as here I just want the value. See [dynamic shift with groupby on dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561454/dynamic-shift-with-groupby-on-dataframe).  If possible I'd like to avoid an apply for performance reasons as I have 10s of millions of rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Account': [1000001, 1000001, 1000001, 1000001, 1000001, 1000001, 1000001,
                    1000001, 1000001, 1000001, 1000002, 1000002, 1000002, 1000002,
                    1000002, 1000002, 1000002, 1000002, 1000002],
        'Date': ['Jan-18', 'Feb-18', 'Mar-18', 'Apr-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18',
                 'Jul-18', 'Aug-18', 'Sep-18', 'Oct-18', 'Jan-18', 'Feb-18',
                 'Mar-18', 'Apr-18', 'May-18', 'Jun-18', 'Jul-18', 'Aug-18',
                 'Sep-18'],
        'Valuation':[ 50000,  51000,  52020,  53060,  54122,  55204,  56308,  57434,
                     58583,  59755, 100000, 102000, 104040, 106121, 108243, 110408,
                     112616, 114869, 117166],
        'Shift': [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]       })
```

The desired dataframe looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Your data construction doesn't run.

Comment: `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

Comment: Apologies, this has been fixed now

Comment: 1- Do you want to group by `Account` like you said or `['Account', 'Date']` ? Because your desired df is grouped by account & Date.  2- I don't think I understood the calculation behind `Valuation Shifted`, can you try another explanation ?

Comment: It's really just by Account.  "Valuation Shifted" is just the Valuation column shifted by minus df['Shift'].  So in the case of account 1000001 df['Shift'] is 3 therefore I'm looking forward three rows in the df['Valuation'] column and picking the value in that row as "Value Shifted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out.

```
def sh(x):
    s = df.loc[x.index, 'Shift']
    return (x.shift(-s.iloc[0]))
df['Valuation_shifted']= (df.groupby('Account')['Valuation'].apply(sh))
```

I know you said you did not want to do apply. But in this case, we are not doing lambda apply. Rather, we are doing a function that finds out the first value of the column 'Shift' in each group & shifts 'Valuation_shifted' by that much.

Comment: What if the Shift value was not the same even within the group, i.e., grouping no longer matters so that each row could have a unique shift value?

Comment: Actually let me correct that to say that grouping does matter but the values for each row within the group could vary for the "Shift" field

Comment: i am not very sure. if you put that as a new question, I am sure someone may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You likely have far more unique accounts than shifts, so instead we will loop over the small number of shifts. Given the sorting on `'Account'`, a `where` checking Account is equal to the shifted Account ensures it's within group.

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series()
for shift in df.Shift.unique():
    u = (df[df.Shift.eq(shift)].Valuation.shift(-shift)
           .where(df.Account.eq(df.Account.shift(-shift))))
    s = s.combine_first(u)

df['Valuation Shifted'] = s
```

---

```
    Account    Date  Valuation  Shift  Valuation Shifted
0   1000001  Jan-18      50000      3            53060.0
1   1000001  Feb-18      51000      3            54122.0
2   1000001  Mar-18      52020      3            55204.0
3   1000001  Apr-18      53060      3            56308.0
4   1000001  May-18      54122      3            57434.0
5   1000001  Jun-18      55204      3            58583.0
6   1000001  Jul-18      56308      3            59755.0
7   1000001  Aug-18      57434      3                NaN
8   1000001  Sep-18      58583      3                NaN
9   1000001  Oct-18      59755      3                NaN
10  1000002  Jan-18     100000      2           104040.0
11  1000002  Feb-18     102000      2           106121.0
12  1000002  Mar-18     104040      2           108243.0
13  1000002  Apr-18     106121      2           110408.0
14  1000002  May-18     108243      2           112616.0
15  1000002  Jun-18     110408      2           114869.0
16  1000002  Jul-18     112616      2           117166.0
17  1000002  Aug-18     114869      2                NaN
18  1000002  Sep-18     117166      2                NaN
```

Comment: Thanks this is great!